# No picture when sharing video from Google photos on Facebook

Tags: facebook, google-photos

Why is this happening? In my Google photos on some video when I click share - get link or share / Facebook - getting link for Facebook. It almost never displays the video thumbnail in a post. Just a big empty white rectangle with *"Photos by ..."* title which is not really nice and probably discourages people instead of attracting their attention. In some cases the preview picture appears but I really don't know why/when. If I do get shareable link it's the same. Somebody please just try pasting this link on your Facebook and let me know if it shows picture or blank rectangle.
https://goo.gl/photos/dzPajcNeVM715Neu7
In some cases the picture is there but mostly no.

Comment: It is showing pic for me.